# How is InnoDB recover ? the crash happenning when buffer_pool memory copy to double_write_buffer

Tags: mysql, innodb

I know that double-write is purposed to solve the partial-page-write problem.but how to recover when the crash happenning during buffer_pool memory copy to double_write_buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a crash occurs during the write to the double-write buffer, that's okay. After the crash, InnoDB recreates the modified page in the buffer pool by reading the original page (on disk) and applying changes recorded in the redo log. Then the write to the double-write buffer can be attempted again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Does that means that the partial-page-write problem can't be solved without double-write  because the original page data has been overwritten due to the partial-page-write ?

Comment: Correct — that's the reason the double-write buffer was created. If you use a filesystem that ensures atomic writes (e.g. ZFS or Ext4), then that already protects against partial page writes, so you can disable the double-write buffer. Example: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/